# My Minecraft account has been messed with

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I opened the Minecraft launcher today and was not able to log in, so I went to Minecraft.net and was still not able to log in. I was able to change my password and email, and need to import my account into my new email. When I attempted to do so, even with my updated password, it did not work. My username must have been changed, does anyone know a way to get my account back?

Comment: [Support](https://help.mojang.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Your best course of action is to perform an account recovery, if possible. This is best done through Mojang's support contact -

https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/emails/new?ref=footer

You should read through the sections on "Minecraft Login," and "Account support for Mojang and Minecraft Accounts," and then I would recommend sending an e-mail to Mojang Support, who will be able to help you resolve the issue directly.